# Restrict permission to custom modules in drupal

Tags: 7, users

I am using drupal 6, and I have created a custom module. This module consists of a form that can be used for adding records to the database.

But I saw that the link to this form (`http://localhost/drupal/my_module/form`) is accessible to all the users, even anonymous users.

I want to restrict the access to this module and form from all the normal users. I want  only the administrator to access it.

I have created a role called Administrator and permitted my module only for the administrator. It still doesn't work.

How can I restrict the access to my custom module ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Declare a permission with [hook_perm()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_perm/6). It is recommended to somehow use your module name in the permission or something unique to your module to avoid conflicts (there is no namespacing, permission names are global).
2. In your [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_menu/6) implementation, add `'access arguments' => array('permission name here')`. Since the default access callback is [user_access()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_access/6), the menu system will call `user_access('your permission name')` to check if the current user has access to that menu item. See [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_menu/6) documentation for more information. You can also use `user_access()` directly in your code, if you want to check permissions somewhere else; for example for blocks, you can use that function directly.
3. Then, you can create whatever roles you want to and give them the permissions of your module at admin/user/permissions. The important distinction here is that permissions are controlled in modules (which can be more or less generically written) while roles and the permissions they have are site-specific.

Then, make sure to rebuild the menu (by using devel.module or saving the modules form) and you should be good.

Comment: Thanks, in my hook_perm() method, i am returning permission like: **return array('admin_only');** and in my form generation code, i checked it like this: **if(user_access('admin_only')) return $form;**

Comment: @dskanth When the full form should not be visible to users without the right permission, it's rather better to use the access arguments in `hook_menu()` as reported by Berdir, than conditionally return the form array basing on the user's permissions.

Comment: I'd put it more strongly than this. Using the access control provided by hook_menu is the right way to do it and you should avoid performing access control checks in callbacks. They make your code less flexible and harder to integrate with other modules.